# ZeroDivisionError even after using try and except

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# program to print the reciprocal of even numbers

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

try:
    assert num % 2 == 0

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print(err)

except:
    print("Not an even number!")

else:
    reciprocal = 1/num
    print(reciprocal)
```

The code is not working and giving me below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-ce890375558f> in <module>
      8     print("Not an even number!")
      9 else:
---> 10     reciprocal = 1/num
     11     print(reciprocal)

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: You didn't wrap the correct code with `try/except`... `num % 2 == 0` will not raise a `ZeroDivisionError` (as nothing is divided by zero...) and anyway it is inside an `assert` statement... As you can see from the error message, the error comes from `reciprocal = 1/num` which is in the `else` part...

Comment: Also num % 2 is not checking for num == 0 -- It's checking whether a number is even.

Answer (score 0):

The line "reciprocal = 1/num" muss be in the try section. Something like this:

```
# program to print the reciprocal of even numbers

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

try:
    assert num % 2 == 0
    reciprocal = 1/num
    print(reciprocal)

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print(err)

except:
    print("Not an even number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think `0 % 2` should raise `ZeroDivisionError`? It's simply 0.

There's no need for exceptions when checking whether the number is even, and this is definitely not what `assert` is intended for. Instead, just use an `if`:

```py
if num % 2 == 0:
    try:
        reciprocal = 1/num
        print(reciprocal)
    except ZeroDivisionError as err:
        print(err)
else:
    print("Not an even number!")
```

Whether exceptions should be used to handle the case `num == 0` is a matter of style (I would personally just use an `if` statement here too). In Python, using exception handling for such cases is somewhat more idiomatic than in most other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't wrap the correct code with `try/except`... `num % 2 == 0` will not raise a `ZeroDivisionError` (as nothing is divided by zero...) and anyway it is inside an `assert` statement... As you can see from the error message, the error comes from `reciprocal = 1/num` which is in the `else` part.

You should wrap the proper code with error-handling, the `assert` can go separately:

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

assert num % 2 == 0, "Not an even number!"
try:
    reciprocal = 1/num
    print(reciprocal)
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    print(err)
```

Unless you don't want an (assertion) error raised so you can do something like:

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

try:
    assert num % 2 == 0
    reciprocal = 1/num
    print(reciprocal)

except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    print(err)

except AssertionError:
    print("Not an even number!")
```